# Is there a command in Linux/Unix to comment out multiple lines at once?

Tags: linux, oracle, unix

I am looking for command or a shortcut to comment out multiple lines at once in Linux/Unix. For example, in a file we have 200 lines and I want to comment first 100 lines only. I know we can use # before every line to make it as comment. But is there a way to do all 100 lines at once and save time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, using sed:

```
sed -i '1,100s/^/# /' file
```

`-i` makes sed modify `file` in-place; `1,100` is the range of lines 1–100 in the file; “s” is for “substitute”; `^` is the beginning of the line; `#`  is its replacement.

Comment: Since the question is also tagged "unix", it should be noted that the `-i` option is not standard and many implementations of `sed` do not support it.  (Also, it is misnamed in gnu-sed, since it does not do the replacement in line but creates a new file and then moves it to have the same name as the old file, breaking links in the process.)